# Powershell get case sensitive path as displayed in windows

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm looking for a way to get the my local path that includes any camel cases that are used in the names.  The primary reason is so I can use the same path to make a call in windows wsl.  For example, in windows I can call a file as

```
c:\FoO\bar.txt 
c:\Foo\Bar.txt
```

and windows will display it as `c:\foo\bar.txt`.  When I try to enter the WSL with bash I need to know the actual path since Linux is case sensitive.

I have tried using

```
$PSScriptRoot
Split-path C:\FoO\Bar.txt
(get-Item c:\Foo\Bar.txt).FullName
```

but they will only provide the path that to call the script.
How do I get my path as it's displayed in the windows os? 
I can't just call the full path of the file I need since I can't guarantee the root directory it starting from.  I also don't want to burn up cycles doing a find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is to look at the `Target` property you get back from `Get-Item`. `Fullname` will come back however you typed it initially, but `Target` is actually a code property that seems to get the raw path of the object.

```
(get-Item c:\Foo\Bar.txt).Target
```

Comment: That gives me exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! 
` 
>pwd 
Path
 ---- 
C:\Users\foo\source\repos\ 

PS > (get-item ("c:\users\FOO\SOURCE\REPOs\")).target
C:\Users\foo\source\repos
PS > (get-item ("c:\users\FOO\SOURCE\REPOs\")).FullName
C:\users\FOO\SOURCE\REPOs\

`

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: Target is empty here :-(. I use powershell 5 on Windows 10

Comment: Other solution : https://serverfault.com/a/431685

Answer (score 1):

from windows 10 onwards, the `Target` property is empty.
`(Get-Item '....')` doesn't contain any property that holds the case sensitive name.

however, when getting all child items of a folder, you get all the names case sensitive.

so my solution is like this:

```
$myCaseInsensitiveFileName = 'c:\FoO\bar.txt'

$allFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\' -Recurse
$caseSensitiveName = $allFiles.FullName | Where-Object { $_.FullName -eq $myCaseInsensitiveFileName }
```

`$caseSensitiveName` holds `C:\Foo\Bar.txt`.

note:

- this can be optimized, but you get the idea.
- the `-eq` operator compares strings case insensitive

Comment: A one-liner that doesn't require recursion: `(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Split-Path $somePath) | Where-Object Fullname -eq $somePath).Fullname`

Answer (score -3):

Find the directory with Windows File Explorer and it shows full path name.

Find the directory in WSL or PowerShell and "pwd" or "echo $PWD" gives full path name. 
Add directory to PATH in $HOME/.profile and you don't need full path name.

Comment: I'm not manually doing anything, I need an automated way to determine this. :-(  This path will vary per user that runs it. I can't expect it to always run from c:\foo it may be c:\bar\foo or e:\x\y\z\foo, e:\X\y\X\Z\foo.  I'm not running this from my machine, this is apart of some other automation that will be running.

Answer (score -3):

I have some automated ways to do it. 

See http://ContextKnowledge.blog

"myenv package for Windows 10 + Cygwin + WSL/Ubuntu"

The package includes a few short shell scripts 

which find the information and record it in environment variables.

If these shell scripts don't work for you, contact me with more details

 and I'll figure out something that will.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18846444)

Comment: NightOwl1888: Download the myenv package. If you think all the shell scripts should be posted here, you are welcome to do so.